# When I try to scrape some URL, it returns "no tables"

Tags: python

I have two URLs.

It wont return any tables. My goal is in the end, to count the number of product categories on the sites.

I understand the problem lies in the structure of the html. I have tried different solutions with pythons pandas, but nothing helps.

Can you help?

What I hoped, was just to get the data with pandas.

I have tried

````
import requests

URL = 'http://semleragro.dk/brugte-maskiner/brugte-maskiner/'
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

row = soup.find('tr') # Extract and return first occurrence of tr
print(row)            # Print row with HTML formatting                                                                            ```

I tried a simple
````

import pandas as pd

wiki_timeline = pd.read_html('http://semleragro.dk/brugte-maskiner/brugte-maskiner/')

```
What I actually needed, was to be able to import the data into excel. But sorry for concerns about the links!
```

Comment: Show us a minimum reproducible example so we can understand the source of the error

Comment: Also, I would advise against anyone clicking unknown links, such as the ones you've posted.

Comment: Hi guys.

Nothing wrong with the links - If you google the companies, you will find them there :) . But sorry for that - I understand your concern. I updated my post again

Comment: Questions here cannot depend on links to third party sites. You need to include sample input for your code here, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a 404 when I visit the second link.

For the first link, if you take a look at the html, there are no `<table>`, `<tr>`, or `<td>` HTML tags anywhere. That's because most of the page is wrapped in an `<iframe>`, with the source being https://dealers.mascus.com/semleragro/search.aspx.

If you scrape that instead, you'll have more luck:

```
def main():

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    url = "https://dealers.mascus.com/semleragro/search.aspx"

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "list list_vertical"})

    for row in table.find_all("tr", {"class": "item"}):
        cell_2 = row.find("td", {"class": "cell2 cell_brandmodel"})
        title = cell_2.find("a").text
        print(title)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Amazone UG3000
Amazone UG3000
Hardi 2800 L 20 M TRAILER
Hardi TZ-TX 2400
John Deere
John Deere
John Deere 732 20M
John Deere 740 24M
John Deere 740I TRAILERSPRØJTE
John Deere 832I
John Deere 832I
John Deere M740 TRAILERSPRØJTE
Kuhn 5600I MARKSPRØJTE
Kuhn METRIS 4102 24M
Case IH MXM 190
Case IH PUMA 230 M/FRONTLIFT
Case IH PUMA CVX230
CLAAS AXION 850
CLAAS XERION 4000
Deutz 615S
```

You don't even need pandas for this. Just BeautifulSoup and requests.

EDIT - I've taken a look at this link:

https://www.kragmann.dk/da/brugte-maskiner/entreprenor.html/#/

I'll admit, finding the "source" for this one isn't as straightforward.

The first thing I did is look at what my browser (Chrome) sees when the page is fully rendered. If you have Chrome, you can do this by pressing F12 and looking at the "Elements" tab - and then expand and collapse the HTML-tag tree view as you like. Most modern browsers support a feature like this. In any case, what you see in this tree view is not necessarily the same as what you would see just looking at the raw HTML source code, since this view is made up of all HTML elements, including the ones that are generated dynamically by JavaScript or by other means. Here's what I saw in the tree view:

[image]

The individual "ads" (vehicles for sale) are under the "external-wrapper" div, which is under the "usedMachines" div. The fact that the div is called "external-wrapper" is a clue that it's contents are being generated by some script.

Then I took a look at the actual source code of the page (in Chrome, right-click -> "View page source") - it looks different from what we just saw in the tree view:

[image]

I can see the "usedMachines" div, but the "external-wrapper" div is not there. As suspected, it is being generated using JavaScript and JQuery. Normally, this is where I would suggest you use Selenium, but I dug a little deeper.

Just above the "usedMachines" div, there is a `<script>` tag, which looks like this:

`<script src="https://lister.maskinbladet.dk/system/data/loader3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
Taking a look at the source code for that JavaScript file, at the very top, you can see some interesting variables, such as:

`basePath = 'https://lister.maskinbladet.dk/system/data/'`
Visiting that URL gives me a 403 error. The page informs me that my access was denied because I didn't submit the correct credentials. Fortunately, we can see in the JavaScript some of the payload keys (GET-parameters) it expects to see:

```
defaultConfig = {
        type: 'normal',
        count: '1',
        callbackURL: '',
        fncallback: '',
        hashtype: 'normal',
        showall: false,
        fbshare: false
...
```

I'd like to scrape this basePath url. So, now I have a url, and I know that I'll have to spoof my credentials and GET-parameters. Looking down a little further I see this:

`ajaxUrl = basePath+'jsonp3.php',`

Which is good to know. This is the actual url we want to scrape.
The code then goes on populating a `ident` dictionary/map (short for "identity" I'm guessing) with GET-parameters. You could try to reverse-engineer the whole thing to get the final list of GET-parameters, but it's easier to just grab them from Chrome's resource log, which I'll do in a bit.

We're almost done looking at the JavaScript - one more interesting snippet is the following: I was just curious to see where `ajaxUrl` ends up being used - namely in this function:

```
function JSONajax(attr, callBack) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl, type: 'GET', data: attr, dataType: 'jsonp'
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if (typeof(callBack) === 'function') callBack.call(this, data);
    });
}
```

It looks like this function accepts two parameters, `attr` and `callback`. The function then makes a GET request to our `ajaxUrl`, and passes `attr` along with the request. That tells me the first parameter must be some kind of collection of payload- or credential key-value pairs. It then binds the second parameter, which is a function, as a callback to be triggered when a response is received. If you search the JavaScript for "JSONajax", you will be able to confirm that the `ident` dictionary/map is passed in as the first argument, which is just more proof that the `ajaxUrl` is the url we want to scrape.

Now I just need to spoof my credentials and GET-parameters. In Chrome, hit F12 and then open the "Network" tab. I then started recording the network traffic and refreshed the page. I looked for "jsonp3.php", and the log shows this request-response history:

[image]

Which reveals all GET-parameters in the request url. A little further down we also get our credentials and a prettier view of the GET-parameters. How convenient!

[image]

All that's left to do is to write a python script to do the actual scraping, which looks something like this:

```
def main():

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    base_path = "https://lister.maskinbladet.dk/system/data/"
    ajax_url = base_path + "jsonp3.php"
    headers = {
        "Referer": "https://www.kragmann.dk/da/brugte-maskiner/entreprenor.html/",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "no-cors",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }
    params = {
        "callback": "jQuery112409740978028988687_1570979614706",
        "locationGUID": "E3EBC2C4-A913-4B75-8918-3BFC7851EF31",
        "version": "adlist",
        "count": "1",
        "showall": "true",
        "fbshare": "false",
        "showyh": "false",
        "pager": "false",
        "contact": "false",
        "noPrice": "false",
        "prefix": "true",
        "orderbyBrand": "false",
        "languageGUID": "63927773-3f10-4874-b08f-823e9aa456ee",
        "currencyGUID": "51597510-a206-4353-ae21-ce8d648fe948",
        "treeGUID": "f268d600-625f-4650-ab91-b3cfef4c9f0d",
        "_": "1570979614707"
    }

    response = requests.get(ajax_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    assert response.status_code == 200

    # Unfortunately, the response isn't raw HTML - there is HTML but it's encapsulated by JQuery stuff...
    text = response.text[response.text.index("<div"):-4].replace("\\", "")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    for ad in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ad-detail"}):

        attributes = ["brand", "model", "price"]
        infos = []

        for attribute in attributes:
            try:
                info = ad.find("div", {"class": f"ad-{attribute}"}).text
                assert info
                infos.append(info)
            except (AttributeError, AssertionError):
                infos.append("N/A")

        for attribute, info in zip(attributes, infos):
            print(f"{attribute}: {info}")
        print()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

There are a few hacky things I did here - so there's plenty of room for improvement. The output:

```
brand: Hyundai
model: R16-9 
price: 158.000,- DKK

brand: JCB
model: 8050RTS
price: 250.000,- DKK

brand: New Holland
model: E18C
price: 155.000,- DKK

brand: New Holland
model: E60C 
price: 576.900,- DKK

brand: Takeuchi
model: TB230
price: 270.000,- DKK

brand: Takeuchi
model: TB230
price: 285.000,- DKK

brand: Volvo
model: ECR25D
price: 175.000,- DKK

brand: New Holland
model: L125 
price: N/A

brand: - - -
model:  Perkins 1104 Motor
price: 38.000,- DKK

brand: JLG
model: 4013
price: N/A

brand: New Holland
model: LM6.28 
price: N/A

brand: New Holland
model: B115C TSS
price: 889.300,- DKK

brand: New Holland
model: BRUGT MOTOR NH 95 / LB 
price: N/A

brand: - - -
model: DIVERSE SKOVLE
price: N/A

brand: JST
model: KIPBAR PLANERSKOVL
price: 14.000,- DKK

brand: JST
model: N/A
price: N/A
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That comment helped me so much! :)

Comment: Can I ask, where you would find the source for this: https://www.kragmann.dk/da/brugte-maskiner/entreprenor.html/#/? - I being trying to go through the html, but cannot find it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! Regarding this new link, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: OMG! That reply is probably the best reply I have ever gotten and is the best reply I have ever seen. That must have taken some time for you! But thank you so much sir! I truely respect people like you, who takes the time to dive into this. There are many things in this, I would never have figured out myself. Have a very good night - Now I have to read your text a few times, to understand it :D